# Can't assign a pointer to primitive in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am wondering why this can compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char *str[3];
    char x = 'a';
    char *px;
    px = &x;
    str[0] = px;
    return 0;
}
```

while this cannot:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char *str[3];
    str[1] = &'a';
    return 0;
}

decla.c: In function ‘main’:
decla.c:9:14: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

Comment: @claptrap: A good, non-trivial question. It's got to be *somewhere* in memory, after all. Your program is obviously able to access it, otherwise `printf("%c\n", 'a');` couldn't work. I think this is more a "how C works" thing, rather than because `'a'` conceptually somehow isn't anywhere at all.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: It doesn't have to be somewhere in memory; it's likely to be stored only in a register, or only in a field of a CPU instruction.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Both of those things qualify as "memory", or at least, a CPU instruction has to be contained in memory before it can be executed.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Loading a constant into a register doesn't require the full representation of the constant to be part of an instruction. In i386 you can `mov` from 8-bit immediate to 32-bit register. `'a'` might look like `0x00000061` in memory but the instruction just has `0x61` as a single-byte operand. In PowerPC, all immediate operands are 16 bits, so a 32-bit constant is *never* contiguous in the object code. There's an instruction to load the high half from a 16-bit immediate, then an instruction to add the low half from another 16-bit immediate. The constant itself *is* "nowhere at all".

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: After the process you've described, it's in the register, so it most definitely is not "nowhere at all". The two halves of it are also in the object code, contiguous or not. It may not be easy to get at, but it's there, and it's capable of being got at.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths But there's no address `p` that could be generated such that `*p` equals `'a'` - which is what `&'a'` would mean

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: In that particular case, there's no address in the object code, but that's simply because you have engineered that example. You don't *have* to do it this way. You could drop it into a data segment and have your instructions read it indirectly, and if C required an implementation to be able to take the address of a character constant, it would have to do something like that, just like it has to do it right now with string literals. The point is that `&'a'` is not illegal because it somehow can't be done, as the original comment intimated.

Comment: Pointers point to variables. 'A' is not a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several replies say that you can only take the address of named variables, but that's not entirely right: if you're using C99 or greater, you can also take the address of a compound literal or a field of a compound literal. Usually this is useful for e.g. calling a function that takes an in pointer to some struct, which you only need to create for the duration of the call. Example: `draw(&(struct point){ 5, 10 });`

Some avenues by which this could be used to obtain the address of a scalar [edited with explanations]:

```
// create a char array containing only 'a', dereference to get 'a', and take its address
char *c = &*(char[]){'a'};  

// same as above, but using an array subscript
char *c = & (char[]){'a'}[0];        

/* create a literal for one unnamed struct containing only the char member "c",
   access .c, and take its address all in the same statement */        
char *c = &(struct{char c;}){'a'}.c;
```

And for the duration of the containing block, *c will equal 'a'.

However the terser and more common way of obtaining an address to a literal using compound literals is simply to declare an array literal with only one element, which will decay to a pointer as usual on assignment:

```
char *c = (char[]){'a'};
```

And this is fairly typical syntax for the job. But as it turns out, the language allows us to do something even more direct and slightly unintuitive: we can declare a compound literal of a scalar type. Which reduces everything above to the more obvious:

```
char *c = &(char){'a'};
```

In your case,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char *str[3];
    str[1] = &(char){'a'};
    return 0;
}
```

It's a little more verbose than '&' and in fact only a few keys less than assigning a temp variable, but there it is.

Comment: Amazing. I don't understand such terms as *compound literal or a field of a compound literal*, is there a good book on such topics of very basic computer science?

Comment: Right, I should have explained a bit further what happens there. A compound literal is just what it sounds like: a way of creating a literal value (like 1, 'a', "hello") for types that hold multiple values like structs, unions, and arrays. So accessing a field in this context means the same as with a regular struct or array. This is mainly just a syntactical feature of the C language, so any material targeting C99 or greater ought to cover it.

Comment: @qed You google them. Right? (Oh, and this is not "basic computer science", that would be things like algorithmic analysis and whatnot. This is programming, and those two are quite different.)

Answer (score 9):

Put a little simplistically, you can only take the address of a variable; a literal like `'a'` is not a variable.

> ### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators
>
> #### Constraints
>
> ¶1 The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
>   `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
>   not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.

The quote from the standard means that you can use:

- `&array[i]`
- `&*ptr`
- `&function`

or a variable, or a member of a structure or union type:

- `&var`
- `&ptr->member`
- `&obj.member`

Etc.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the address of operator only works on *names*.

```
char character = 'a';
str[1] = &character;
```

should work just fine.

The reason why `&'a'` doesn't work is because there is no guarantee that a value even has an address.  It may be loaded directly from the code pages into the register, in which case it is not in reference-able memory, or at least doesn't lie in the memory that you *should* be dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet is working fine as in that you are taking the address of the variable.

In the second code snippet:-

```
str[1] = &'a';
```

This is not the correct way. 'a' isn't a variable. and address operator of operator works on names.
If you want this to work then change it like:-

```
 char c = 'a';
 str[1] = &c;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jonathan said, you can only take the address of a variable. Under the covers, that 'a' is really just a short integer (ASCII value of 'a'). So, it's the same as why you can't do this:

```
str[1] = &9;
```

Comment: In C (but not in C++), `'a'` isn't a short integer; it's a constant of type `int`.

Comment: Perhaps he meant to say "small integer".